# SQL, cursor, перебор, добавляется две записи вместо одной

Tags: sql-server, циклы, cursor

Пытаюсь с помощью курсора перебрать исходные данные и для каждой записи сделать те или иные изменения. Вот сам запрос:

```
DECLARE @ID bigint --id attachments
DECLARE @personID BIGINT
DECLARE @territoryServiceID BIGINT
DECLARE @isAtClosed BIT

DECLARE @currentServerDate DATETIME = '2016-01-01 01:10:00.000' --this change GETDATE()
DECLARE @BeginDate DATETIME SET @BeginDate = @currentServerDate
DECLARE @periodYear INT SET @periodYear = DATEPART(YEAR,@currentServerDate) - 1

DECLARE cur cursor LOCAL STATIC
FOR
SELECT at.id, at.personID, at.territoryServiceID, ts.isClosing
FROM Attachments at
INNER JOIN Person p ON p.id = at.personID AND p.parentID IS NULL
INNER JOIN TerritoryServices ts ON ts.id = at.territoryServiceID
LEFT JOIN Attachments at2 ON at2.personID = at.personID AND at2.parentID = at.id AND at2.attachmentStatusID IN (2,11,12)
WHERE at.attachmentStatusID = 1 AND at.causeOfAttachID = 8 AND at.endDate IS NOT NULL
AND at2.id IS NULL
AND p.id IN (15300000019296419,15300000018501113,15300000014988209,414674754,420940229,409531785)


OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @personID, @territoryServiceID, @isAtClosed
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
DECLARE @personID_NVARCHAR NVARCHAR(MAX) SET @personID_NVARCHAR = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@personID)
PRINT '1 ('+@personID_NVARCHAR+')'

IF (@isAtClosed = 1) -- if ter of CA is closing
    BEGIN
        -- Insert error into ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach
        DECLARE @ErrorDescr NVARCHAR(MAX) SET @ErrorDescr = 'TerId: ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@territoryServiceID)
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach] ([AttachmentsID],[personID],[territoryServiceID],[periodYear],[reasonError],[addDate],[description])
        VALUES (@ID, @personID, @territoryServiceID, @periodYear, 1, GETDATE(), @ErrorDescr)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @terAt2ID BIGINT
        DECLARE @isAt2Close BIT = 0
        SELECT @isAt2Close = ts.isClosing, @terAt2ID = ts.id FROM Attachments at 
        INNER JOIN TerritoryServices ts ON ts.id = at.territoryServiceID
        WHERE at.personID = @personID AND at.attachmentStatusID = 2 AND at.endDate IS NULL

        IF (@isAt2Close = 1) -- if ter of attach is closing
            BEGIN 
                -- Insert error into ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach
                DECLARE @ErrorDescr2 NVARCHAR(MAX) SET @ErrorDescr2 = 'TerAttachId: ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@terAt2ID)
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach] ([AttachmentsID],[personID],[territoryServiceID],[periodYear],[reasonError],[addDate],[description])
                VALUES (@ID, @personID, @territoryServiceID, @periodYear, 2, GETDATE(), @ErrorDescr2)
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN 
                BEGIN TRY
                BEGIN TRANSACTION TranName
                    -- Search active request
                    DECLARE @ID_zapros BIGINT 
                    SELECT @ID_zapros = id FROM Attachments WHERE personID = @personID AND endDate IS NULL AND attachmentStatusID != 2 AND id != @ID
                    IF (@ID_zapros IS NOT NULL) 
                        BEGIN
                            -- Canseled request

                            -- Block #1
                            -- Create cancel for active request
                            INSERT INTO Attachments (personID,orgHealthCareID,personAddressesID,territoryServiceID,attachmentProfileID,doctorID,
                                causeOfAttachID,careAtHome,senderRequestID,senderSystemID,attachmentStatusID,beginDate,endDate,parentID,userID,registratorID,
                                actualAttachmentID,ConflictAttachment,Node,regDate,isMigrated,isDuplicate,oldPersonID,servApplicationID,Num)
                            SELECT at.personID,at.orgHealthCareID,at.personAddressesID,at.territoryServiceID,at.attachmentProfileID, at.doctorID,
                                8,at.careAtHome,NULL,NULL, 11, @BeginDate, @BeginDate, at.id, 
                                at.userID, at.registratorID, at.actualAttachmentID, NULL,NULL,at.regDate,NULL,0,at.oldPersonID,NULL,at.Num
                            FROM Attachments at 
                            WHERE at.id = @ID_zapros

                            -- Set endDate for active request
                            UPDATE Attachments SET endDate = @BeginDate WHERE id = @ID_zapros
                        END

                    --Search active attach
                    DECLARE @ID_prikrep BIGINT
                    SELECT @ID_prikrep = id FROM Attachments WHERE personID = @personID AND endDate IS NULL AND attachmentStatusID = 2
                    IF (@ID_prikrep IS NOT NULL) 
                        BEGIN
                            -- Block #2
                            -- Insert detach
                            INSERT INTO Attachments (personID,orgHealthCareID,personAddressesID,territoryServiceID,attachmentProfileID,doctorID,
                                causeOfAttachID,careAtHome,senderRequestID,senderSystemID,attachmentStatusID,beginDate,endDate,parentID,userID,registratorID,
                                actualAttachmentID,ConflictAttachment,Node,regDate,isMigrated,isDuplicate,oldPersonID,servApplicationID,Num)
                            SELECT at.personID,at.orgHealthCareID,at.personAddressesID,at.territoryServiceID,at.attachmentProfileID, at.doctorID,
                                8,at.careAtHome,NULL,NULL, 8, @BeginDate, @BeginDate, at.id, 
                                at.userID, at.registratorID, at.actualAttachmentID, NULL,NULL,at.regDate,NULL,0,at.oldPersonID,NULL,at.Num
                            FROM Attachments at 
                            WHERE at.id = @ID_prikrep

                            --Set endDate for active attach
                            UPDATE Attachments SET endDate = @BeginDate WHERE id = @ID_prikrep
                        END

                    -- Attach CA
                    INSERT INTO Attachments (personID,orgHealthCareID,personAddressesID,territoryServiceID,attachmentProfileID,doctorID,
                        causeOfAttachID,careAtHome,senderRequestID,senderSystemID,attachmentStatusID,beginDate,endDate,parentID,userID,registratorID,
                        actualAttachmentID,ConflictAttachment,Node,regDate,isMigrated,isDuplicate,oldPersonID,servApplicationID,Num)
                    SELECT at.personID,at.orgHealthCareID,at.personAddressesID,at.territoryServiceID,at.attachmentProfileID, at.doctorID,
                        8,at.careAtHome,NULL,NULL, 2, @BeginDate, NULL, at.id, 
                        at.userID, at.registratorID, at.actualAttachmentID, NULL,NULL,at.regDate,NULL,0,at.oldPersonID,NULL,at.Num
                    FROM Attachments at 
                    WHERE at.id = @ID

                COMMIT TRANSACTION TranName

                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TranName

                    -- Insert error into ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach
                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach] ([AttachmentsID],[personID],[territoryServiceID],[periodYear],[reasonError],[addDate],[description])
                    VALUES (@ID, @personID, @territoryServiceID, @periodYear, 3, GETDATE(),ERROR_MESSAGE())
                END CATCH
            END
    END

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @personID, @territoryServiceID, @isAtClosed
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Запрос для курсора возвращает 6 строк(6 выбраны для примера), то есть все ID уникальные, ничего не задваивается. Далее в зависимости от определенных условий производятся те или иные действия, прошу обратить внимание на два блока действий (в комментариях называется Block#1 и Block#2), именно они ведут себя странно.

После выполнения запроса на какой-нибудь (тут тоже важно, не всегда на одной и той-же записи, бывает то на одной то на другой, а то и на двух) записи задваиваются строки с данными, то есть вставляется две строки у которых все данные кроме автоинкрементного идентификатора повторяются! Причем если откатить действия и попробовать только на этой записи на одной (то есть цикл прогнать для одной записи) все завершается отлично! Вот такие-вот злые электрические силы. Непонятно почему так происходит, подскажите кто-нибудь что не так, или в каком направлении искать решение?

P.S. триггеров на вставку данных на таблице Attachments нету. Строки всегда вставляются после всех действия, то есть допустим первое условие выполняется, вставляется строка 1, затем по второму условию вставляется строка 2, затем строка 3, и в случае если происходит задвоение строки, то она вставляется самой последней, то есть после строки 3 вставляется строка 4 идентичная строке 1 (или строке 2 когда как)

Comment: Вы бы в тегах И в тексте вопроса указали какой именно SQL используете. По внешнему виду похоже на MS Sql server или Sybase но штатная гадалка в отпуске

Comment: Извиняюсь, первый вопрос на данной площадке. Используется MS SQL Server

Comment: А не пробовали сразу после fetch какую нибудь инфу из него просто в какую нибудь тестовую таблицу записать, что бы посмотреть сколько он строк реально вернул. Когда то очень давно, когда я работал с Sybase курсоры себя вели нестабильно, если в них менять таблицу из которой они читали. Проблему решало добавление `FOR UPDATE` к запросу курсора. Но с MS SQL я никогда не сталкивался, так что просто предположение

Comment: Попробовал, поставил запись в начале после fetch и в конце после fetch, в итоге в начале записалась только первая запись, а в конце записались 2,3,4,5,6 и еще раз 6ая, почему то в конце две шестых записалось, но по данной записи не было задвоения, задвоение произошло на 5ой строке...

Comment: Не, значит курсор сам себя ведет правильно. Две 6-е это нормально он потом из цикла уходит когда вверх поднимется и условие проверит.   А вот в чем тут дело тогда совершенно не ясно. записи в этих блок1-2 же явно отличаются какими то цифрами... У вас курсор не выбирает 2 записи с 1 presonid вы же потом по нему что то порверяете и вставляете. И у вас там какого нибудь поля не особо нужного нет, типа комментария что бы туда заодно вставить at.id изначальной записи из курсора ...

Comment: @Mike спасибо огромное за помощь! Ваша подсказка с записью идентификатора в какое-нибудь поле, принесла свои плоды и я разобрался в чем причина! Вот только не знаю как Вас отблагодарить и пометить Ваш ответ. Хочу также чуть позже написать решение к которому я пришел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью **Mike** удалось найти решение данной проблемы! Тут я изложу все поподробнее вдруг кому-то поможет.
Итак, начнем. Результат запроса для курсора:

[image: Результат запроса для курсора]

... как видно никакого дублирования идентификаторов нет

С подсказкой Mike(спасибо огромное), в одно из полей (Node) записал id записи в переборе, в результате получил следующее:

В первой записи все отлично, не будем ее рассматривать.
Вторая запись по списку id = 14308060, personID = 414674754. В результате произошло задвоение (Block #1), но в поле Node видим, что в конце записался идентификатор следующей по порядку записи!!!

[image: Вторая запись курсора]

Ниже приведен результат следующей записи:
[image: Третья запись курсора]

... тут все нормально

Далее..
Пятая запись id = 148362023, personID =  15300000018501113. В результате прошло задвоение (Block #2), опять же в поле Node идентификатор следующей записи

[image: Пятая запись курсора]

Ниже результат следующей записи в которой все ровно:

[image: Шестая запись курсора]

Итак, все это навело на мысль, значения в переменных остаются прежними если в результате установки возвращается NULL, хотя в каждом цикле переменная объявляется заново. 
Теперь смотрим что происходит:
1. Выполняется обработка второй записи, так как у нее есть активный запрос то следующее выражение:

```
DECLARE @ID_zapros BIGINT 
SELECT @ID_zapros = id FROM Attachments WHERE personID = @personID AND endDate IS NULL AND attachmentStatusID != 2 AND id != @ID
```

записывает в переменную @ID_zapros идентификатор 150118746, далее выполняется все как нужно, добавляется ровно столько записей сколько нужно, последней записи, которая дублируется еще пока нет!

2. Далее выполняется обработка третьей записи. У данной записи активного запроса нет, поэтому следующее выражение возвращает NULL

   SELECT @ID_zapros = id FROM Attachments WHERE personID = @personID AND endDate IS NULL AND attachmentStatusID != 2 AND id != @ID

но! в переменную @ID_zapros записывается не NULL(как я предполагал), а остается предыдущее значение! Вот тут то и зарыта собака. И получается что при обработке третьей записи добавляется еще одна запись в с данными о предыдущей записи...

с 5 и 6 записью все тоже самое, только уже на другом этапе...

Я думал что, так как переменная объявляется внутри цикла, то при каждом объявлении в нее будет записываться NULL, также ошибался что при установки переменной, если результат возвращает NULL, то и в переменную запишется NULL, оказалось совсем не так...

Решение довольно простое, обнулять переменную принудительно, я сделал так:

```
DECLARE @ID_zapros BIGINT 
SELECT @ID_zapros = id FROM Attachments WHERE personID = @personID AND endDate IS NULL AND attachmentStatusID != 2 AND id != @ID
IF (@ID_zapros IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        --Отказываем запрос

        --Создаем отказ активному запросу
        INSERT INTO Attachments (personID,orgHealthCareID,personAddressesID,territoryServiceID,attachmentProfileID,doctorID,
                                causeOfAttachID,careAtHome,senderRequestID,senderSystemID,attachmentStatusID,beginDate,endDate,parentID,userID,registratorID,
                                actualAttachmentID,ConflictAttachment,Node,regDate,isMigrated,isDuplicate,oldPersonID,servApplicationID,Num)
        SELECT at.personID,at.orgHealthCareID,at.personAddressesID,at.territoryServiceID,at.attachmentProfileID, at.doctorID,
                                8,at.careAtHome,NULL,NULL, 11, @BeginDate, @BeginDate, at.id, 
                                at.userID, at.registratorID, at.actualAttachmentID, NULL,@nvar_ID,at.regDate,NULL,0,at.oldPersonID,NULL,at.Num
        FROM Attachments at 
        WHERE at.id = @ID_zapros

        --Закрываем дату активному запросу
        UPDATE Attachments SET endDate = @BeginDate WHERE id = @ID_zapros

        SET @ID_zapros = NULL
    END
```

Извиняюсь за довольно большое изложения, но я впервые здесь, может что-то делаю не так вы уж простите! Еще раз спасибо всем кто откликнулся! Надеюсь это кому-нибудь поможет не напороться на те же грабли)

Comment: В том то и прикол, что утверждение _при установки переменной, если результат возвращает NULL_ неверно. Когда запрос вернул одну строку со значением NULL - то он вернул NULL, а когда запрос не смог выбрать ни одной строки, то он _ничего не вернул_,  а не _вернул NULL_. И когда он ничего не вернул - переменная не меняется. Записывайте подобные запросы в виде `select max(id) from ...` тогда он всегда возвращает одну строку, которая будет NULL, если подходящих данных не найдено.

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо `select max(id) from ...` тоже работает отлично, не знал про это. Да, я может не совсем до конца разобрался в проблеме, но теперь погуглив все наконец прояснилось, вот тут уже есть ответ в 4 пункте [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945361/set-versus-select-when-assigning-variables).

Comment: Я про подобные проблемы давно уже забыл, вот только прочитав ваш пост вспомнил. давно с Sybase не связывался ну и с наследником его MS Sql дел не имел. А в оракле все просто - подобная строка не вернула ничего - скрипт вылетает с ошибкой :) И без `max` или обработки исключений - никак.

Answer (score 2):

Код не самый очевидный, не имея данных сложновато понять, что происходит. Как вариант, для отладки вы можете попробовать добавить `output inserted.*` для всех блоков `insert`, что даст вам возможность посмотреть в каком порядке и какие именно данные были вставлены.

Пример работы `output` блока:

```
declare @attachments table (id int, status_id int)

insert into @attachments (id, status_id)
output 'block #1', inserted.*
values (1, 2)

insert into @attachments (id, status_id)
output 'block #2', inserted.*
select 3, 8
```

Возможно, здесь:

```
SELECT @ID_zapros = id FROM Attachments WHERE ...
```

либо здесь

```
SELECT @ID_prikrep = id FROM Attachments WHERE ...
```

по мере движения курсора выбирается не то, что ожидается.

Comment: И вы были правы насчет того что в данные переменные записывается не то что я ожидал, спасибо! P.S. оказывается моя репутация не позволяет еще лайкать ответы, к сожалению.